# Conditions on sets $A \subset B \subset X$ for the equality $\mu[B\setminus A] = \mu[B] - \mu[A]$ to hold

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be an outer measure for the set $X$ and $A \subset B \subset X$. I am wondering what are the conditions on the sets $A$ and $B$ for the equality $\mu[B\setminus A] = \mu[B] - \mu[A]$ to hold. If both $A$ and $B$ are $\mu$-measurable and $\mu[A] < \infty$, then the proof is equality is quite evident as $\mu[B] = \mu[B \cap A] + \mu[B\setminus A] \Longleftrightarrow \mu[B \setminus A] = \mu[B] - \mu[A]$

Since the measurability of $B$ was not really used, it seems that $B$ does not need to be $\mu$-measurable for the equality to hold. Also if $B$ were to be $\mu$-measurable, but $A$ wasn't event with $\mu[A] < \infty$, then if $X = \{a, b\}, \mu[\{a, b\}]\{a\}] = \mu[\{b\}] = 1, \mu[\varnothing] = 0$, shows that the equality does not hold if $B$ is $\mu$-measurable, but $A$ was not, as if $B = X, A = \{a\}$ we'd have $\mu[X \cap A] + \mu[X \setminus A] = 1 + 1 \neq 1 = \mu[A]$.

In addition the equality can hold only if $\mu[A]$ is finite, as otherwise if $\mu[A] = \infty$, then also $\mu[B] = \infty$ and we'd have $\infty - \infty$ in the rhs of the equation, which is not defined.

Is there anything other to consider?